# Axios delete call returns 405 and I tried to delete node using id but it's not deleting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my code, I tried to delete the record in firebase realtime database using id

```js
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Order.css';
import axios from '../../axios-orders';
const order = (props) => {
    const restult = () => {
        return (props.details.map((item, i) =>
            <tr key={item.id}>
                <td>{i + 1}</td>
                <td>{item.orderData.name}</td>
                <td>{item.orderData.email}</td>
                <td>{item.orderData.street}</td>
                <td>{item.orderData.zipCode}</td>
                <td>{item.orderData.country}</td>
                <td><button onClick={() => deleteHandler(item.id)} >Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        )
        )
    }

    const deleteHandler = (itemId) => {
        axios
            .delete('/orders.json/-LrJSCvoqEKoM1BAfgOV', {
                headers:
                    { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }
            })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.Order}>
            <table className={classes.students}>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Sno</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Street</th>
                        <th>ZipCode</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {restult()}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default order;
```

I have passed `id` to delete function. But it's showing the below error:

> error:OPTIONS https://react-my-project-912f7.firebaseio.com/orders.json/-LrJSCvoqEKoM1BAfgOV 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>
> error:Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://react-my-project-912f7.firebaseio.com/orders.json/-LrJSCvoqEKoM1BAfgOV' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Could you please tell me where I did a mistake? **Thanks in advance**

Below is attached screen shot and I passed the id is "-LrJSCvoqEKoM1BAfgOV"
[Fibercase DB image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSODY.png)

Below is my firebase setting:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://react-my-project-912f7.firebaseio.com/'
});

export default instance;
```

Comment: did you add localhost into your firebase setting?

Comment: just now I added firebase setting in question, and post is working fine but delete not working

Comment: Seem like you've created a function on firebase and that function stopping your requests to reach the server (CORS issue). This might contain some clues that might help you to get rid of CORS issue: https://equimper.com/blog/setup-cors-in-firebase-functions

Comment: Ya, headers also added but same error showing

Comment: Where you added @Ramu? on your client request? It should stay at your server. That's mean your server will accept request from another host. `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` has nothing to do with client request.

Comment: Some progress. I changed url to like this 'https://react-my-project-912f7.firebaseio.com/orders.json',{data:orderData}   it's deleting all nodes

Comment: but I want to delete particular node

Comment: With particular node I think it suppose to be like this `'/orders/-LrJSCvoqEKoM1BAfgOV.json'` or something.

Comment: As u mentioned I tried but It's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Firebase Realtime database stop you to send `OPTIONS` request into their endpoint which doesn't allowed `OPTIONS` method.

From [Saving data document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-delete) from firebase, if your database is like this:

```
- orders
    - -LrJSCvoqEKoM1BAfgOV
        - orderData:
            ...
```

and you want to delete `-LrJSCvoqEKoM1BAfgOV` then your DELETE request url should looks like this:

https://react-my-project-912f7.firebaseio.com/orders/-LrJSCvoqEKoM1BAfgOV**.json**

`.json` stay at the end of the endpoint to inform Firebase to enable cors for your host origin.